# Полька и полячка

Tags: лексика

Пожалуйста, оцените с точки зрения нормативности слова полька и полячка. То, что написано в словарях, я прочла. Но в одном указывается, что полячка - устаревшее, в другом, что разговорное. Нет ли отличий в семантике: например, одно обозначает национальность, другое - жительницу Польши?

Answer (score 3):

Моя сестра, долго жившая в Польше, утверждает, что поляки предпочитают "польку", а "полячку" воспринимают негативно. Для русских "полячка" звучит уменьшительно-ласкательно. Для поляков, увы, это слово имеет оттенок пренебрежения.

Answer (score 1):

Если следовать нормам словообразования, то в РУССКОМ языке правильно будет "полячка" (казак — казачка, узбек — узбечка, таджик — таджичка). Читайте Пушкина и Гоголя, хотя и у классиков встречается вариант "полька".
В языке ПОЛЬСКОМ правильно будет "полька", но мы же говорим о нормах русского, а не польского языка. Великий русский язык всегда вбирал в себя множество иностранных слов и многие делал своими. Кстати, пометки в самых авторитетных словарях, что вариант "полячка" является устаревшим и т. д., делают эти самые словари уже устаревшими, так как появились более современные словари, которые допускают употребление двух вариантов без всяких пометок.
Но и это является только половиной дела, так как было бы правильным к варианту "полька" добавлять пометки *заимствование, иностранное.* Иначе нас скоро заставят писать "в Украине" (вместо "на Украине") или "Таллинн" (вместо "Таллин"). А там и не пройдёт полвека, как вы станете писать "Раша" вместо "Россия". Я, конечно, шучу, но в каждой шутке есть доля шутки.

Comment: *Арх.*,  Когда вы говорите о "нормах русского языка", пожалуйста, подтверждайте свои утверждения ссылками на авторитетные источники. Что касается Пушкина и Гоголя, то с их поры почти два века минуло. Язвк мог сильно измениться. Что, собственно, и подтверждают кодифицирующие источники, дающие **полячка** как разговорное (а то и вовсе устаревающее) к общелитературному **полька**.

Comment: Рассуждения, советы, прогнозы — без аргументов — даже не половина дела.

Answer (score 1):

"Полячка" -- несколько устаревший термин, употреблявшийся в литературе XIX века. Скажем, у Пушкина:

Снег пушистый валится; всадник с ношею мчится,
Черной буркой ее покрывая.
«Что под буркой такое? Не сукно ли цветное?»
«Нет, отец мой; полячка младая».

В современной же речи это слово будет резать слух. Пожалуй, я бы в нём усмотрел и несколько пренебрежительную коннотацию.

Answer (score 0):

`Нет ли отличий в семантике?` Из материалов Википедии следует, что в современном русском языке **полька** – это и жительница Польши ([Польша](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0)), и представительница польского народа ([Поляки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B8)).

Answer (score 0):

**Нет ли отличий в семантике: например, одно обозначает национальность, другое - жительницу Польши?**

Нет. Вообще в русском языке такие семантические различия крайне редки. Кроме собственно "русский-россиянин", трудно что-то вспомнить. Да и "россиянин" стало таким специфическим обозначением относительно недавно.
И уж совсем непонятно было бы иметь семантические различия для особы женского пола, обходясь одним словом "поляк" в мужском случае.

По поводу нормативности. Хотелось бы понять, насколько убедительна упоминавшаяся тут аналогия с узбечкой, казачкой и прочими. Там-то "ка" присоединяется напрямую к корню, а у "поляка" "як" явный суффикс. И с этим суффиксом есть только отдельные примеры наподобие босяк-босячка и менее очевидные маньяк-маньячка. Но можно ли их переносить на название представителей народов?

Comment: Да ладно, вспоминайте, что британцы, бельгийцы, швейцарцы, пакистанцы, индийцы, индонезийцы, югославы – это названия жителей соответствующих стран, а национальностей таких нет. И ещё есть малайцы (национальность) и малайзийцы, жители Малайзии любой национальности, а национальностей там множество.